# Saving a Cloudinary object to a Django Model

Tags: django, cloudinary

I have a model:

```
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField

class Image(models.Model):
    image = CloudinaryField('image')
```

And an object that I received from Cloudinary. It was given to me by Cloudinary after I uploaded an image, and I passed it back to my server:

```
{'etag': ['***'], 'version': ['***'], 'public_id': ['***'], 'type': ['upload'], 'signature': ['***'], 'created_at': ['2017-07-28T15:54:17Z'], 'secure_url': ['https://res.cloudinary.com/***/***.png'], 'height': ['353'], 'format': ['png'], 'resource_type': ['image'], 'url': ['http://res.cloudinary.com/***/image/upload/***/***.png'], 'width': ['684'], 'bytes': ['133509']}
```

I can't seem to save it to my model. I have tried both saving it directly and putting it through the `CloudinaryJsFileField` form in Cloudinary's documentation. Neither seems to work. The form laments that "No File Was Selected" and the model.create() effort complains of a missing property.

This is the form I am using:

```
class PhotoDirectForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['image']
```

I've tried it both with and without `CloudinaryJsFileField`, and I get the same error either way:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_image">Image:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>No file selected!</li></ul><input type="file" name="image" required id="id_image" /></td></tr>
```

Obviously it wants a file, but that's not what Cloudinary gives me after I upload my image!

Does anyone know how to save Cloudinary objects to the Django database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the [Photo album](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-django-sample) sample project?

The flow there is -

views.py -

```
form = PhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
...
form.save()
```

forms.py -

```
class PhotoForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Photo
    fields = '__all__'
```

models.py -

```
class Photo(models.Model):
## Misc Django Fields
create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
title = models.CharField("Title (optional)", max_length=200, blank=True)

## Points to a Cloudinary image
image = CloudinaryField('image')
```

This should save the image both in Cloudinary and your storage.